# only Noteworthy apps are showing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin, site-collection

I am having issues with SharePoint 2013 site content when i try to add a new app, it only shows ***App you can add*** ***and Noteworthy apps (3 apps)*** on all sites and sub-sites, 90% of the Master Pages are customized using the SharePoint Designer but all of them include all the placeholders mentioned in many solutions on the internet, all the needed features features are enabled, and it is getting frustrating since no solution is working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea in the masterpage and it's not commented.

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
```

Comment: Hi @joao the content place holder does exists and not commented. this is weird because all of a sudden this happened, it happened before but on a specific page, the solution was easy. but now it is all over the site collection.

Comment: Can you share your masterpage code?

Comment: sure you will find it in the answer below